# IO Cathode PINOUT

Tags: pins, pinout

I have to connect a peripheral **1-Wire 13.56Mhz RFID Reader**
https://doc.ruptela.lt/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=884781) to a device. 
The only info I have from the device ((**FM-eco4/4+ ruptela**: http://www.ruptela.com/product/fm-eco4/) ) is this one:

```
PIN      WIRE COLOR       DESC
10-32 V      Red           Power supply 12/24 V (range: 10-32 V)
Chassis      Black         Ground connection
DIN1         Pink          Digital input, threshold 4 V
DIN2         Blue          Digital input, threshold 4 V
DIN3         White         Digital input, threshold 4 V
DIN4         Yellow        Digital input, threshold 4 V
AIN1         Grey          Analogue input (range: 0-30 V)
AIN2         Green         Analogue input (range: 0-30 V)
DOUT1        Purple        Digital output open collector up to 32 V, 1 A
DOUT2        Orange        Digital output open collector up to 32 V, 1 A
1-Wire POWER White/red 1-wire power supply, 5 V
1-wire DATA   Green/yellow 1-wire data transfer
```

PINOUT from the peripheral

```
Green : Green LED cathode (-)
Brown : Red LED cathode (-)
```

Probably that's such a stupid question because I have no electronics background at all, but by life things I have to do it

Comment: So your peripheral is an LED and you want to know how to light it from your device? (That's how your question reads.) Why don't you explain what these pieces of equipment are and what you are trying to achieve. Links to datasheets are always a good idea. Put all the information **in the question** and not sprinkled through the comments.

Comment: The answer is: 42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> PINOUT from the peripheral
>
> ```
> Green : Green LED cathode (-)
> Brown : Red LED cathode (-)
> ```

However, according to the [datasheet](https://doc.ruptela.lt/download/attachments/884781/EN%201-Wire%20RFID%2013.56%20MHz%20Datasheet.pdf?version=2&modificationDate=1492157473000&api=v2) for the "1-Wire 13.56MHz RFID Reader", linked on the web page you gave, the pinout is *actually*:

[image: Pinout shown in RFID reader datasheet]

The data transfer occurs using the 1-Wire pin. I don't see any information which suggests the LED connections must be connected at all. They might be included to allow external LEDs to be added, in case the LEDs in the RFID reader are hidden due to its mounting location, for example.

Since you are connecting two devices, both from the same company, then you should be asking *them* for support and information about how to do that.